# Javascript Regex to Java regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following regex in Javascript:

`/^(\{?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}\}?)$/`

It matches numbers like:

087-1234893, 083-2839283, 086-4283944, etc.

I've converted it to Java (Android) as follows:

```
public boolean isValidMobilePhone(String phone){
        boolean returnObj=false;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^({?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}}?)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(phone);
        boolean matchFound = m.matches();
        if (matchFound){
            returnObj=true;
        }
        return returnObj;
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

> 07-12 23:26:10.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11464):
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error
>   U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 3: 07-12 23:26:10.478:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11464): ^({?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}}?)$ 07-12
>   23:26:10.478: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11464):    ^ 07-12 23:26:10.478:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11464):     at
>   com.ibm.icu4jni.regex.NativeRegEx.open(Native Method)

I can't figure out what's wrong with the third '?' character! I tried escaping it with '\', but that won't compile.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Pattern.compile("^08[3-9]-([0-9]){7}$");
```

Or even:

```
Pattern.compile("08[3-9]-([0-9]){7}");
```

Comment: No problem. You might want to get a regular expression cheat sheet next time you work with regular expressions. Also try using baregrep.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `{`, and most likely the `}` near the end as well.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\{?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}\\}?)$");
```

The `{` character is a special character used to repeat (e.g. `a{3,5}` repeats `a` 3-5 times), and needs to be escaped in Java regexes.

Comment: You need two ``\`` to escape it. To be fair, some regex engines take the `{}` literally if the are not used in this `{n,n}` format.

Comment: Sorry, I fell asleep! I'm in work now, but will be back to it later... I'll report back then

Answer (score 0):

need only remove the delimiters

for javascript:

```
var  pattern = /^(\{?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}\}?)$/;
```

for Java:

```
string pattern = "^(\{?(08)([3-9]){1}-([0-9]){7,7}\}?)$";
```

Comment: Hi, when I use that pattern, I get this error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`